# Is there a name for this type of conclusion technique?

Tags: technique, repeats

The name of this song is called "感情の摩天楼 (Emotional Skyscraper)　～　Cosmic Mind, and I have been obsessed with this song since I first heard it years ago, mainly because of how much the way it uses certain music theory elements , but what surprised me the most was this:

[example](https://youtu.be/l46_osXYc3I?t=15)

Around 0:15~0:39 into the video, you hear what appears to be the second half of the intro of the song. I'm particularly interested in those concluding notes {highlighted below}.

[image]

Then, after one minute into the song, this exact same melody comes back in a modulated key, and those last notes return. **But this time, pictured below in measures 54-56, they repeat for an additional 2 measures before finally ending on a B♭m chord, concluding what can be heard as a chorus.**

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have been obsessed with trying to track down the name of this technique. That repeating of those final notes at the end of a phrase of a phrase that is makes a song more impactful and sends chills down my body every single time I hear it. Another example of a song that uses this technique is the end of the Sailor Moon theme in which the song concludes by having the ending of the chorus being repeated at least two times before finally concluding with a modulation of that repeat(measures 92-96).

[image: ![enter image description here]

The closest word I can find for it is a coda or codetta, but I wasn't satisfied with that answer because it can be played in a number of ways, not in this specific way.

(Apologies if any of this sounds confusing, I'm using these terms the best that I can. don't make fun of me)

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you’re asking about but it seems to be related to *phrase expansion* - when a length of phrase is set in the music and then a phrase is written that is longer than the expected length. One type of expansion can be *dominant prolongation*, and as these expansion seem to come before cadential material they might be most similar to that. Not all types of expansion have names. You should expect that there might not be any name at all for what you’re asking about. Not everything has a name.

Comment: I take it that you're interested in the Deep Purple song "Highway Star" as a 3rd example? They sing the chorus-concluding "I'm a highway star!" multiple times in a row at the end, intriguingly *inserting 2/4 measures into this song in 4/4 time* in the process.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Oooooh, I just listened to this song, and that one part in partiicular was pretty interesting! This does kinda match what I'm talking about, though  what I'm thinking of doesn't necessarily have time signature changes, and the repeating only lasts for like two or three measures. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: @ToddWilcox Aw, I was hoping that the video I added would've made it clear, guess not. Though, I did look into what a "phrase expansion" is, and that might just be the closest to answer I have, so that was still very helpful. I guess I could also say that another example of this technique would be the Animaniacs theme song where the Warners repeat the same four notes three times when they sang, "We're animane-y, totally insane-y. [____]," at the end before finishing the song off, but I don't know if that you be any clearer. Still, thanks for you answer!